# inconsistent definition of longitude and latitude for healpy.pixelfunc.get_interp_val() or healpy.mollview()?

Tags: healpy

when I rotate a Healpix map along longitude or latitude, I get the wrong behavior.
I'm probably missing something obvious here but so far, I failed to find what.

See demo:

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nside = 4
npix = hp.nside2npix(nside)

idx = 70
offset = 1 # rad

# set one pixel to 1 in the map
data = np.array(np.equal(np.arange(npix), idx), dtype=float)

hp.mollview(data, nest=True, title='original')

# longitude and co-latitude in radians
theta, phi = hp.pix2ang(nside, np.arange(npix), nest=True)

# rotate: offset on longitude, keep co-latitude the same
rotated = hp.get_interp_val(data, theta + offset, phi, nest=True)

hp.mollview(rotated, nest=True, title='rotated longitude')

# rotate: keep longitude the same, offset on co-latitude
rotated = hp.get_interp_val(data, theta, phi+offset, nest=True)

hp.mollview(rotated, nest=True, title='rotated latitude')
```

and results:

- [original map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quSWr.png)
- [rotated longitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybU16.png)
- [rotated latitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ryho.png)

The dot in the map rotated along longitude is translated vertically, while it is translated horizontally for the rotation along latitude. I'd expect the reverse.

Any hint about what's wrong here?

E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theta is co-latitude, Phi is longitude.
It is confusing because their order is inverted than what we usually expect. In fact even in `healpy`, for example in [pix2ang](https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.pixelfunc.pix2ang.html) if you set `lonlat` to true, you get as outputs first Longitude and then Latitude.
Unfortunately this is the convention and we have to stick to this.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. The doc for pix2ang says : "otherwise, angles will be longitude and co-latitude in radians (default)". It would be less confusing if it were: "otherwise, angles will be co-latitude and longitude in radians (default)"  as in ang2pix and other functions? Cheers, É

Comment: Can you make a pull request to fix that?